# How to get actual enviroment path while using remote debug

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

When using remotedebug,

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

returns a path start with remote machine ip,

how can I get the absolute real path on remote machine?

I tried many other methods that provide a path, such as `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`  but it does not work too